# How to dynamically authenticate user and create calendar event in google

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have been tired of doing google finally decided to post my problem here.

I have a simple requirement, I want to create calendar events in google using calendar api.

I am able to do that but whenever user run my page he has been taken for google authentication page.

I don't want user to take this page. I want that user will enter their email id and will select calendar event on my page further it will update the events to user's calendar and he will remain on my page itself.

In short a simple calendar form where user can enter their email id and credential will select event once submit button is clicked it will update the calendar event to google calendar.

Please find  the below attached image that i don't want to show to user.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you want. In order to create events in the user's calendar, he/she must give you authorization first. This is done through that Google page.

You just need to set a redirect URI for your app in the Developers Console and use it when authenticating the user. This way the user is sent back to your app after the auth process.

Check the docs: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth